# Caching authentication status to improve performance of subsequent messages

Tags: java, performance, security

I'm looking to improve the performance of an application that under load spends the bulk of its processing time in the authentication process (username/password verification).

I'm comfortable with the way the application passwords are stored and verified (salted and hashed with many iterations), the issue is that the authentication process is slow and CPU hungry (which it is supposed to be).

The application gets bursts of messages and every message that comes in gets authenticated. 
Specifically what I'm looking at doing is implementing a short term cache (120 seconds) where if a username/password is successfully authenticated then any additional requests that come in during the cache window with the same username/password are authenticated without the need for going through the slow many iteration authentication process.

The basic process flow would be:

1. Check username is valid and account isn't locked (Suspended/too many retries/Password recently changed)
2. Check cache to see if entry for username/password exists

   - No Entry in cache: pass supplied password through authentication algorithm and compare against value stored in the database. If a match then user is authenticated and an entry added to the cache
   - Entry in cache: Supplied username/password are identical to those authenticated within the cache window so authenticate the user.
3. Cache would auto expire entries

The cache would be an in memory cache but the question I have is how 'secure' do I need to make the data I place in the cache (username/password). Its the trade off between performance and security... and how safe is safe enough.

For example would the following be a reasonable key to use for the cache:

- username + hash(salt + password)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that what you *really* want to do is issue a token/ticket which is valid for the next 'n' seconds. The token would be encrypted/signed such that you alone can validate it and check for expiry (and thus protect against replay attacks)

Comment: If I understand you correctly the token/ticket would be added to the message response... and could be then passed in with subsequent message requests? I will definitely consider that, but the scope of that change is larger that I was hoping to make. Which is a server side only change that doesn't need the message consumer to make any updates.